# Add js file to Magento 2 admin

Tags: magento2, xml

EDIT: After recreating the folder structure the default.xml worked. It was somehow not loaded.

I am trying to add a js file to the backend of Magento 2. I have seen several posts about it and it seems pretty straightforward. However, I can not get it to work... I am working in developer mode so no need to deploy.

This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="Qxs_SerialCodes::js/save.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

app/code/Qxs/SerialCodes/view/adminhtml/layout/default.xml
app/code/Qxs/SerialCodes/view/adminhtml/web/js/save.js

[image: Just to provide some prove...]

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code instead of yours:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="Qxs_SerialCodes::js/save.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

You are doing wrong by adding **link** instead of **script**.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot but it does not work, I tried everything... Emptied all caches and run setup:upgrade still no js file..

Comment: Its a working code. Try again by running static content deploy.

Comment: No need to run it will return [Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException]                                                         
  NOTE: Manual static content deployment is not required in "default" and "developer" modes.               
  In "default" and "developer" modes static contents are being deployed automatically on demand.           
  If you still want to deploy in these modes, use -f option: 'bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f'

Comment: Coul it be the js file causing the issue?

Comment: Put alert('Yeah! its working'); to your save.js and remove the other codes from save.js and check if its showing the alert or not? if you need to run the static content deploy on developer mode then you need to run the command: setup:static-content:deploy -f

Comment: Just to be sure i ran static content deploy and only added an alert to the js file, still no result. The funny thing is there are other modules using the same code and there it is working... Could it be the namespace?

Comment: Not sure as you have placed the js in proper place and also namespace and module name looks fine. Try it in private browser once.

Comment: I have added an image of my IDE and files... No result in private browser, unbelievable...

Comment: I tried to put a bug in my xml file but it seems not to be loaded at all

Comment: Can you check if your module is enabled or not?

Comment: It is the code is working, just not loading default.xml

Comment: I have added the file to another module where it is working now, but this is very strange... My modules default.xml is not loaded. Thanks for the help!